# Adding a new electrical line for light sockets to insulated garage

Tags: electrical, garage

Adding a series of light sockets to my garage. Garage is insulated and I am running line through the studs.  Two questions:

1. Can I run the wire on top of the insulation or cut insulation and run behind?
2. Best way to tape up the rips in the insulation paper?

Thanks,
Dave in Maryland

Comment: Are you running through ceiling, wall or floor? What sort of construction? What sort of insulation? What sort of wiring - cable or conduit? What do you mean by on top? Photos would help a lot here.